# Best place to add to Drupal.settings from a theme

Tags: 6, theming, hooks, javascript

I am working on a theme for a client, and have run into an instance where I would like to add to `Drupal.settings` via [drupal_add_js()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/6) from the theme.

In this particular case, it is really most appropriate to do it from the theme itself and not a module hook, as the setting is related to the theme itself.

Doing it from [template_preprocess()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess/6), or one of its relatives, is too late because `$vars["scripts"]` has already been built.  I suppose I could do something like the following code, but this doesn't seem right.

```
$settings = array(
  "bar" => "bar",
);

drupal_add_js(array("foo" => $settings), "setting");

$vars["scripts"] = drupal_get_js();
```

Is doing it from [hook_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_theme/6) really the only option, or is the above approach kosher?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have seen that pattern multiple times before, and it seems to be a standard practice.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record I had a similar problem today and solved it using [hook_preprocess_hook()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7) to intercept my theme function, no messy `$vars['scripts']` exists yet

Comment: Looking back, I am not sure why my question got tagged for Drupal 7.  It was actually about Drupal 6, where the options are more limited.  Your solution is a good one for Drupal 7.